# When my elements have flex-direction: column they no longer have transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three buttons, each with their dropdown menu which is toggled on click. The dropdown menu has a transition of `transition: all 0.2s` and it works just fine when they are displayed as `flex-direction: row`. Now I have a media query that displays them with `flex-direction: column` and for some reason they no longer have transitions.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
let arrow = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow-pag');
let dropMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.link-dropdown');



Array.from(buttons).forEach((el, index) => {
  let toggled = false;
  el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (toggled) {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      el.style.color = "var(--midnightBlue)";
      arrow[index].style.borderColor = "var(--midnightBlue)";
      arrow[index].classList.toggle('up-pag');
      dropMenu[index].style.height = "0px";
      toggled = false;
    } else {
      console.log(index);
      el.style.backgroundColor = "var(--midnightBlue)";
      el.style.color = "white";
      arrow[index].style.borderColor = "white";
      arrow[index].classList.toggle('up-pag');
      dropMenu[index].style.height = "100%";
      toggled = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --fontSansSerif: 'Inter';
  --fontSerif: 'DM Serif Display';
  --heightDropdown: 250px;
  --bluePigment: #333895;
  --midnightBlue: #1B1164;
  --aliceBlue: #E4EBF8;
  --lightSteelBlue: #B0C5E3;
  --darkSteelBlue: #86ADE3;
}

.pagini-folositoare,
.toate-linkurile {
  width: 100%;
}

.toate-linkurile {
  font-weight: 500;
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}

.link {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: var(--midnightBlue);
  transition: all 0.15s;
}

.link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link-container {
  width: 33%;
}

.link h2 {
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrow-pag {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.down-pag {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.15s;
}

.up-pag {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.link-dropdown {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0px 10px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.link-dropdown ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.link-dropdown ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 790px) {
  .toate-linkurile {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .link-container {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .link {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pagini-folositoare">
  <h1>Pagini folositoare</h1>
  <div class="toate-linkurile">
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="link">
        <h2>MEDIA<i class="arrow-pag down-pag"></i></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="link-dropdown height">
        <ul>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">aaaa</a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">bbbbb</a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">cccc</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="link">
        <h2>CLUBURI<i class="arrow-pag down-pag"></i></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="link-dropdown height">
        <ul>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">link 1</a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">link 2</a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="link">
        <h2>ADMITERE<i class="arrow-pag down-pag"></i></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="link-dropdown">
        <ul>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">aaaa</a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">bbbbb</a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">cccccc</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I don't know if I did something wrong in my code or if I'm missing a transition somewhere, but I can't figure this out

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because when in `flex-direction: column`, the `height` of each `link-container` item need to be specified for a transition of `height` to work.

Since this does not seem practical in this use case, you could use `flex-wrap: wrap` instead of `flex-direction: column`.

```
@media all and (max-width: 790px) {
  .toate-linkurile {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

This will make the transition of `.link-dropdown` happen, which hopefully achieves the desired result without major changes of the existing code.

Full example:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".link");
let arrow = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow-pag");
let dropMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".link-dropdown");

Array.from(buttons).forEach((el, index) => {
  let toggled = false;
  el.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (toggled) {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      el.style.color = "var(--midnightBlue)";
      arrow[index].style.borderColor = "var(--midnightBlue)";
      arrow[index].classList.toggle("up-pag");
      dropMenu[index].style.height = "0px";
      toggled = false;
    } else {
      console.log(index);
      el.style.backgroundColor = "var(--midnightBlue)";
      el.style.color = "white";
      arrow[index].style.borderColor = "white";
      arrow[index].classList.toggle("up-pag");
      dropMenu[index].style.height = "100%";
      toggled = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --fontSansSerif: "Inter";
  --fontSerif: "DM Serif Display";
  --heightDropdown: 250px;
  --bluePigment: #333895;
  --midnightBlue: #1b1164;
  --aliceBlue: #e4ebf8;
  --lightSteelBlue: #b0c5e3;
  --darkSteelBlue: #86ade3;
}

.pagini-folositoare,
.toate-linkurile {
  width: 100%;
}

.toate-linkurile {
  font-weight: 500;
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}

.link {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: var(--midnightBlue);
  transition: all 0.15s;
}

.link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link-container {
  width: 33%;
}

.link h2 {
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrow-pag {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.down-pag {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.15s;
}

.up-pag {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.link-dropdown {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0px 10px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.link-dropdown ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.link-dropdown ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 790px) {
  .toate-linkurile {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .link-container {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .link {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pagini-folositoare">
  <h1>Pagini folositoare</h1>
  <div class="toate-linkurile">
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="link">
        <h2>MEDIA<i class="arrow-pag down-pag"></i></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="link-dropdown height">
        <ul>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">aaaa</a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">bbbbb</a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">cccc</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="link">
        <h2>CLUBURI<i class="arrow-pag down-pag"></i></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="link-dropdown height">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="link">
        <h2>ADMITERE<i class="arrow-pag down-pag"></i></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="link-dropdown">
        <ul>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">aaaa</a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">bbbbb</a></li>
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com">cccccc</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```